# How to load application.conf in Akka

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

can anyone help me with the following question.
I am using play frame work and Akka. My programming language is Java. I am trying to use Akka Cluster. In Akka doc, it is said that the application.conf shall be put in src/main/resources. However in Play frame work, there is no folder named src. So I have to create the folder src and put the application.conf there. Also I put my code in src/main/java/sample/cluster/simple. But it seems the application.conf cannot be loaded in the ActorSystem. I tried

```
System.out.println(system.settings());
```

But I did not see any changes of the configuration. If I put all the configuration details in

```
Config config = ConfigFactory.parseString("...")
```

It works very well. Does anyone know what is worn here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In Play, `application.conf` is traditionally kept in the `conf` directory.  It's not clear from your question whether you're using a Play project or a vanilla SBT project.  Ultimately, the location of the config file will come down to what you've defined as your resources directory.  From your SBT console, you can do `show unmanagedResources` to get a list of these locations and the files currently loaded as resources.

In Play, you can access the current config through `play.api.Play.current.configuration`.  In Akka, you can use `myActorSystem.settings.configuration`.  Or, within an actor: `context.system.settings.configuration`.

Note that both Play and Akka use Typesafe's [config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) for parsing config files.  It's quite powerful but you don't need to know all the details to get started.